# How to get clientId and clientsecret for Azure (ARM) deployment template

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I want to automate my Azure resource management, and I'm using the ARM templates to do so.

If I want to connect to Azure from my C# code (the DeploymentHelper.cs that is generated when downloading an Azure export template).

The code is asking for the following details:

```
        string subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";
        string clientId = "your-service-principal-clientId";
        string clientSecret = "your-service-principal-client-secret";
        string resourceGroupName = "resource-group-name";
        string deploymentName = "deployment-name";
        string resourceGroupLocation = "resource-group-location"; // must be specified for creating a new resource group
        string pathToTemplateFile = "path-to-template.json-on-disk";
        string pathToParameterFile = "path-to-parameters.json-on-disk";
        string tenantId = "tenant-id";
```

I can see the tentantId and subscriptionId via powershell, but I have no clue how to get the clientId and clientsecret, and I cant find any solid instructions on how to get these either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you created a service principal in AD? If so, you should have these values. If you haven't, follow the msft guide.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/

Comment: Thanks, got my clientid etc working, still cant manage to add the application as 'a user'  to my azure portal though...

Comment: The application just doesn't show up in the list of 'users' when doing Add users. I checked that I'm working in the same subscription.

Comment: nevermind, I was working in the wrong AD directory. Gonna try again.

Comment: @EdwardRixon Here is the way to do it from the portal, I found it easier than running the powershell commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal - maybe you can add it to your response.

Answer (score 1):

1. Azure portal
2. Active Directory
3. App registrations (on the right panel)
4. Click the correct Application (client) ID
5. You will see then under overview.

[image]